# how to resize button in a animation javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm using an animation in javafx so when I click on button it move with an animation but I want to also resize it (It should become smaller and smaller).

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        /*Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));*/
        AnchorPane root=new AnchorPane();
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        Button button = new Button();



        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                        new KeyValue(button.translateXProperty(), 500),
                        new KeyValue(button.translateYProperty(), 500)),

                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.5), // set end position at 40s
                        new KeyValue(button.translateXProperty(), 200),
                        new KeyValue(button.translateYProperty(), 200)));



        timeline.play();


        root.getChildren().addAll(button);
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to animate the node's scaleProperties:

```
timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                                       new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                                                    new KeyValue(button.translateXProperty(), 500),
                                                    new KeyValue(button.translateYProperty(), 500),
                                                    new KeyValue(button.scaleXProperty(), 1),
                                                    new KeyValue(button.scaleYProperty(), 1)),

                                       new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.5), // set end position at 40s
                                                    new KeyValue(button.translateXProperty(), 200),
                                                    new KeyValue(button.translateYProperty(), 200),
                                                    new KeyValue(button.scaleXProperty(), .4),
                                                    new KeyValue(button.scaleYProperty(), .4)));

        timeline.play();
```